# PDF file editing save and read editable file again

Tags: ios

I have a problem that PDF file editing . From my app, when an OpenIn menu is shown, I'll choose an application to open the file adobe reader in iphone device( ex:UIDocumentInteractionController to share with adobe  reader) and the PDF file is opened for edit in Adobe-reader.  But after editing, how can I send it back to my app or get the link where that editable PDF is saved ? How can I get this file?

Comment: Hi did you get a solution for it ?