# PDF File Editing and Read Editable file in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf

I have a problem that PDF file editing . From my app, when an OpenIn menu is shown, I'll choose an application to open the file PDF Expert in iphone device( ex:UIDocumentInteractionController to share with PDF Expert) and the PDF file is opened for edit in PDF Expert. But after editing, how can I send it back to my app or get the link where that editable PDF is saved ? How can I get this file?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878508/pdf-file-editing-save-and-read-editable-file-again

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you app registers it self that it can also open PDF file. Then if PDF Expert  has an option the open the file in an other app the user will be able to open it your again.

There is not build in feature in the iOS SDK that lets you get a file from an other app.